# ruby on rails css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to color my view using css. The controller is workflows_controller. Hence i added the following code to the workflows.css.scss:

```
.folder_section {
  text-align:center;
  color: #244;
}
```

My view is

```
<div class="folder_section" id="folder_section">
                <%= form_for :folder_name, :remote => true, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "show"} do |f| %>
                <%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first)%>
                <%= f.submit "Submit folder"%>
                <% end%>
</div>
```

The select box is aligned to the center but i could not see any color. I copy pasted the same code in the view itself. But still i could not see any color. Please let me know why the select box is aligned to the center but not colored. I looked into the web and some pdf documents. Everyone says that the controller.css.scss will take care of styling when you add the css code to it.
Thanks

Comment: The css color attribute is for setting the font color and the color you chose is quite close to black so you may not see a change. Have you tried to set the background-color attribute to #244? Or try to change the select field color attribute by defining it in the code .folder_section { select { color: #244; } }

Comment: @Stevens this seems to be the correct answer, why have you posted it as a comment?

Comment: Hi Stevens, that works. Thank you. I changed the background color in controller.css.scss file and it is reflected on my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css color attribute is for setting the font color and the color you chose is quite close to black so you may not see a change.

Have you tried to set the background-color attribute to `#244`?

Or try to change the select field color attribute by defining it in the code

```
.folder_section { 
  select {
    color: #244; 
  }
}
```